# System.Runtime.Seralization.SeralizationEception Error occurring on Azure Active Directory B2C integration with xamarin pcl app

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

System.Runtime.Seralization.SeralizationEception Error occurring on Azure Active Directory B2C  integration with xamarin pcl app for login/register system. Visual studios isn't showing any error in code. I have got guidance from this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/tree/master/UserDetailsClient)!
In App.cs i am doing this

```
// Azure AD B2C Coordinates
    public static string Tenant = "example.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static string ClientID = "123whatever789";
    public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "example";
    public static string PolicyEditProfile = "example";
    public static string PolicyResetPassword = "example";

    public static string[] Scopes = { 
"https://appname.onmicrosoft.com/appname/read" };
    public static string ApiEndpoint = 
"https://appname.azurewebsites.net/appname";

    public static string AuthorityBase = 
$"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
    public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";
    public static string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase} 
{PolicyEditProfile}";
    public static string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase} 
{PolicyResetPassword}";

    public static UIParent UiParent = null;



    public App()
    {
        // default redirectURI; each platform specific project will have to 
override it with its own
        PCA = new PublicClientApplication(ClientID, Authority);
        PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{ClientID}://auth";
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Does the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) work for you? Can you provide logs or the full stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: No jenny , It didn't worked. I've just duplicated other files i my project. I am going to develop Custom Login system using C#.

Comment: Which error message did you get when running the sample? The same listed above? Which platform (iOS, Android, UWP) are you using? Is it working on any of the platforms? I am able to get this sample to work, so would like to try and repro your issue if possible. Thanks.

Comment: System.Runtime.Seralization.SeralizationEception,,,, (a long error). Platforms are Android and iOS. I am testing it on android using VS xamarin.

Comment: Rest of the code is same as the code provided in this sample.

Comment: Jenny, does this sample worked for you?

Comment: Thanks. maybe i am doing any mistake.

Comment: I'm able to run the sample. Can you provide the entire error message?

Comment: I've come to know that you work at Microsoft so, you will surely solve this.  Actually I've removed this code. I am going to re implement this sample. Do you have any suggestion for me about implementation of this code. Does App.cs will be updated like i had done above this page? Thank you ma'm

Comment: I would go through the readme of the sample to help set everything up correctly. You can also open an issue on the sample if you are having problems getting it to work.

Comment: Oh, i did't subscribed the AD b2c directory before. Do they allow UI customization in ADb2c in free subscription? and thats a great of yo to provide that much help.

Comment: Yes - UI customization is free in B2C up to 50K users and authentications. Here is a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) that might provide more info on UI customization.

Comment: That's superb. I would like to use B2C sometime and let you know in case of any problem. Currently going for my project owner's demand for custom login system. All the best